# PostgreSQL pg_stat_activity gets filled with "SET extra_float_digits = 3" query causing Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

The problem is `pg_stat_activity` getting filled with `SET extra_float_digits = 3` query, causing `Error calling Driver#connect` when number of rows reaches the `max_connections` limit (100 in my case). I tried uncommenting the `#extra_float_digits = 3` line in `postgresql.conf` file, but that didn't work. I read something about setting this property in pgbouncer `ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits`, but I don't know what pgbouncer is and how to install/configure it - it seems a bit too complicated.
I also tried setting this connection parameter in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file: `<property name="assumeMinServerVersion">9.0</property>`, but that didn't work either.

Is there any way that you guys know of which can solve this issue without increasing the connection limit and without using pgbouncer maybe? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I search for hour about this problem and did not found any mention of **assumeMinServerVersion** configuration directly inside the *hibernate.cfg.xml*.

I not sure that it is possible.

The only way I found to solve this problem of **SET extra_float_digits = 3** that is killing my connections is applying the **assumeMinServerVersion** directly into the JDBC connection URI, like this:

```
String url = “jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=myuser&password=mypass&assumeMinServerVersion=9.0”;
```

Which are indicated [here](https://medium.com/@tk512/postgresql-extra-float-digits-log-spam-bf22f390ebf5), [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488849/how-do-i-pass-a-jdbc-paramater-using-springboot-and-hibernate).