# How do i pass a jdbc paramater using springboot and hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-boot

I have an application written with spring-boot (i am new to it so please forgive me if question is dumb) that uses hibernate 4 and postgresql as DB backend.
I noticed a bunch of connections on the DB that belong to the connection pool stating: "SET extra_float_digits = 3"

Googling around, I've found that it is probably due to the use of the old protocol and that could be avoided using the *assumeMinServerVersion* parameter of the jdbc driver.
Now my question is: how do i pass / set that parameter from a spring-boot application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) you could set a `assumeMinServerVersion` parameter in the jdbc url, something like

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?assumeMinServerVersion=XYZ
```

Comment: Do I have to change it to assume-min-server-version if I am using application.yaml?